# How to add fluent animation to this jquery code?

Tags: jquery

I need to add some smooth animation effect for transitions to my jQuery code but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
<!-- https://codepen.io/marsucz/pen/QWyGPrB -->
```

Any ideas? Thank you a lot!!

Comment: https://codepen.io/marsucz/pen/QWyGPrB

Comment: Please include the code *in the question* - you can edit and click `[<>]` and copy-paste into the snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do it show/hide you can use .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() for showing/hiding elements with a transition. You can set the transition speed like this: .fadeIn(1000)